# State of the art incremental decision tree learners

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree, data-stream

What are the state of the art algorithms for incremental decision tree learning? The only algorithm that works well and that I'm aware of is the Domingos-Hulten VFDT and its extensions.

Answer (score 0):

see https://github.com/greenfish77/gaenari
gaenari is c++ incremental decision tree.

Minimize concept drifting damage.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31245777)